# No cells found error

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am getting a `Run Time Error 1004 No cells found` when I run this code to get the row number of blank cell.

```
Sub gg()

MsgBox ActiveSheet.Range("a8:a800").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row

End Sub
```

I am getting this error for this range only `A8:A800` on my worksheet, if I change the range to `A1:A7` it gives me the first blank cell within this range but for anything beyond `A7` it gives me a run time error. All cells after `A7` are blank on my worksheet. I'll appreciate any help on this.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Finding the first blank in column A?

Comment: if you are, for the first cell of the range, over the ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row, you have an error...

Comment: Are there any blank cells in "A8:A800"?  My instincts say to avoid using the "SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)" function and opt to iterate through each cell and check for emptiness.

Comment: I have a lot of data so iterating through each cell takes too long.Yes all cells a8:a800 are blank. I am trying to find the first blank cell in the range and write data to it

Answer (score 0):

You may find success with:

```
MsgBox Intersect(ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.Range("A8:A800").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)).Row
```